# How could this Firefox bookmark title have changed to my password?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Ok, here's a mystery case I'm struggling with.

A friend of mine uses Firefox (currently 54, Windows, 64 bit). He has only one single bookmark in his bookmarks bar: his email service. Today, he launches Firefox and notices something rather strange. 
The text of the label next to the email service favicon in the bookmark button is no longer the name of the email service but...

...his **email password**! Or, part of it, all characters but the very first one to be specific. In clear text!

He immediately calls me, and I insist on a Teamviewer session, because I don't believe him. But he's telling the truth.

Here is a recreation of the situation, I made a screenshot on different machine (with more bookmarks) and I obviously used a different password. This is just to give you an impression:

[image: dramatic recreation of mystery bookmark]

`gstTG5tf66` is the almost complete password in cleartext. This used to be the email service's name up until today. Only the first character is missing.

*How did he manage to do that?*

I have no clue. My friend is a senior citizen. I suspect he might have expected to focus the password input field when actually something entirely different was focused, but the bookmark's properties dialog is hard to enter by accident.

I'd like to read your theories!

Comment: "How did he manage to do that?" - He likely hit a keyboard combination, was attempting to type his password, but ended up changing the name of the bookmark itself.  "I'd like to read your theories!" - This is specifically out of scope here at Superuser.

Comment: If his password starts with a capital “D” then he might have hit CTRL+D instead in which case he would have go directly to the page bookmark window with the title highlighted and ready to change. Try it out and you’ll see what I mean.

Comment: @bashBedlam This is the most likely explanation. Nice thinking :)

Comment: A very good explanation @bashBedlam, but not the correct one. There was no capital D in the entire password. But maybe this really isn't the right forum for speculation...